# How to Refer to Multiple Columns in a Table by Number

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use Application.Match to find a row of a table and store it in an array. I have it working for searching a single column:

```
With Worksheets("Data").ListObjects(tblName)
    myArray = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.ListRows( _
         Application.Match(searchTerm, .ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, 0 _
    ).Range)))
End With
```

But some of the tables I want to look at with this sub might have the `searchTerm` in column 2, so I want to expand the range refered to in `Application.Match" to the 1st and 2nd columns. I've heard about using`.Resize(,2)` but i cannot get it to work. Today I found out about structured referencing and I can reference the columns like this:

```
Worksheets("Data").Range("tblName[[Column1]:[Column2]]").Activate
```

But this requires I refer to the columns by their header name, which differ between tables, and I want to be able to use their number. Does anyone know a solution that doesn't involve looping if the `searchTerm` isn't found in the first column?

Update:

To provide more info on my question.

1. The user selects a cell, which contains a string. The string is split into 2 elements in the array `instruction`.
2. `instruction(0) =` the name of the table i want to look in. `instruction(1) =` the term i am searching for. This term could be in column 1 or 2.
3. The row of table `instruction(0)` that contains `instruction(1)` is then loaded into another array named `interactData`
4. Each table has its own sub that uses the elements of `interactData` to do different things.

Comment: `Match` typically doesn't work on multiple columns.

Comment: Does `Find` not work for you?

Comment: ^ Second the use of `Find`.

Comment: I'm open to using `Find()`,  i'm just lost in how to call out the first two columns in the range object

Comment: What results exactly are you expecting? Perhaps post a screenshot.

Comment: Also, what happens if what you are looking for appears more than once in these columns? which instance would you want and how do you decipher which one to select?

Comment: I dont plan on reusing terms within a table, and I will probably setup conditional formatting to highlight duplicates so i can fix them. I added more info to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a workaround i was able to come up with:

```
Dim headers As Variant
headers = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Data.Range(instruction(0) & "[#Headers]")))
interactData = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Data.ListObjects(instruction(0)).ListRows( _
Data.Range(instruction(0) & "[[" & headers(1) & "]:[" & headers(2) & "]]").Find(instruction(1)).Row - 2 _
).Range))
Erase headers
```

I used another array `headers` to store the names of the columns, and then used `headers(1)` and `headers(2)` in the structured referencing for the `Range().Find().Row` function. Unfortunately `.DataBodyRange` doesn't play nice with this method so I had to subtract 2 from the row result because row 1 of the table is in row 3 of the sheet.